# Sort Listbox items by user score

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting

i want to show top users by they scores that stored in a listbox like this:

```
user1:95
user3:80
user2:90
user4:120
```

The output must be:

```
user4 score: 120
user1 score: 95
user2 score: 90
user3 score: 80
```

My current code is:

```
    string[,] users = new string[listBox1.Items.Count, 2];
    int[] scores = new int[listBox1.Items.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        string[] s = listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Split(':');
        users[i, 0] = s[1];
        users[i, 1] = s[0];
        scores[i] = int.Parse(users[i, 0]);
    }
    Array.Sort(scores);
    Array.Reverse(scores);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(users[i, 1] + " score: " + scores[i]);
    }
```

Output:

```
user1 score: 120
user3 score: 95
user2 score: 90
user4 score: 80
```

user name is not correct.
thanks.

Comment: What is the current code you have ? What kind of application you are targeting ASP.Net Or WinForm or any other ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WinForms solution: Copy items to an array, sort the array, then print the array:

```
string [] items = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
listBox1.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);
Array.Sort(items, delegate(string a, string b) {
    // Should add error checking here in case string in wrong format
    int ascore = Int32.Parse(a.Substring(a.IndexOf(':') + 1));
    int bscore = Int32.Parse(b.Substring(b.IndexOf(':') + 1));
    return ascore == bscore ? 0 : (ascore < bscore ? 1 : -1);
});
foreach(string s in items) {
    Console.WriteLine(s.Replace(":", " score: "));
}
```

**EDIT:** Problem solved by changing a to b on line 6.

Comment: Error: Failed to compare two elements in the array. :(

Comment: please note that users name length is not equal.

Comment: My code works with different length names. But won't work if string is not in format: <string name>:<int score>.

Answer (score 0):

Cast to a List and then use LINQ's order by:

```
// order
List<UserScore> scores = new List<UserScore>(listBox.Items.Cast<UserScore>());
var orderedScores = scores.OrderBy(li => li.Score).ToList<UserScore>();

// re-populate the ListBox
listBox.Items.Clear();
listBox.Items.AddRange(orderedScores.ToArray<UserScore>());


public class UserScore
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

This is simpler than using `ListBox.Sort()`

Comment: Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'UserScore'.